# Iscroll Different Starting Locations Depending on previous Page

Tags: scroll, position, iscroll4, iscroll

Basically what I'm trying to do is, I have an Iscroll with say 10-20 Images in a general proejct page, and each links to a Detailed Page of that Project. In the Project page, it uses Iscroll again to do the same where I can scroll through the Detailed pages of projects in the same order as the general project page.
Is there a way to link them, so depending on which project I click on in the General project page, to have it go the the same detailed page?

General page scroller:  a,b,c,d,e,f,g
Detailed page scroller: A,B,C,D,E,F,G

so when click d, it will take to me location D within the scroller

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what you exactly mean but you can scroll to realtive position on click of `d` by using `scroller.scrollTo(x,y,0)` or also use `scroller.scrollToElement('div:nth-child(D)', 100)`. Check the section **Javascript scrolling** in http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 for reference. Hope this helps

Comment: yea, definitely. I'm aware of the position function. The trick for me is, how to anchor it so that the position changes when you go to the page depending on what element on a previous page was clicked.